# What is the difference between POP3, IMAP and Exchange?

Tags: gmail, imap, exchange-server, pop3

I'm trying to set up a Gmail account on a sony xperia sl and it's asking me to choose between POP3, IMAP or Exchange. which one am I supposed to use ?

Comment: What does "email clients" mean ?! i googled a lot and i still can't decide which of them is better !

Comment: This a programming site. Are you planning on developing emailing software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OT, and I have voted to close in such. In any case, here an expansion. (Note how much general computing information can be found on Wikipedia these days!)

An [e-mail client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) is the email program (e.g. what access the the e-mail in Sony Xperia) used to connect to the e-mail server (e.g. gmail). [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol), [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP) and Exchange (primarily used with Outlook) are 3 different protocols for e-mail clients and e-mail servers to communicate.

Gmail supports only POP3 and IMAP and these must first be "activated". See [Gmail: Get Started with IMAP and POP3](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=1668960&from=12103&rd=1) for instructions on how enable access from Gmail and configure the e-mail client.